# Changing width of an absolute positioned div

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a slider. When a user moves the slider, I have a `div` that expands over another `div`. I do this by changing the `width` and `left` style attributes of the `div`. For example, when the page loads, the `div` looks like this:

```
<div class="vr" style="left: 100%; width: 0%;"></div>
```

When the user moves the slider, the `left` and `width` style attributes are dynamically changed so it will look something like this:

```
<div class="vr" style="left: 85.1859753886784%; width: 14.8140246113216%;"></div>
```

However, is there anyway to expand this `div` without changing the `width`, and only changing the `left` style attribute? For example, by keeping the `right` attribute alway at 0 and changing the `left` style attribute, can the `div` be expanded? E.g. something like:

```
<div class="vr" style="left: 85.1859753886784%; right:0;"></div>
```

From my experiments, it only expands if `width` is set as the user moves the slider...

Comment: why dont you use transition??

Comment: What do you want? First you are saying that you don't want to change the width then you are asking for a way to expand the div!

Comment: yes, expand it by changing the left and right attributes only..

Comment: Well if you want to expand something then until and unless you use either `width` or `padding` the only other way is to use simple html. Because left and right are only supposed to be there for positioning.